# Pass language on Forgotten password with error AADB2C90118

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have custom policies for all my authentication scenarios. I didn't use the new recommended sub journey pattern because I need to get back to my own site for some validation questions. It was simpler to do this instead of having to migrate some sensitive data to B2C for this purpose. So when the user clic "Forgotten password" link, it returns an "access denied AADB2C90118" error. I then trap it within my MSAL plugin and do my things. Everything works fine, except for the language.

In our custom version of the "unified.html" template, we added a link to change language. Its just a link on the same page with a different "ui_locales" request parameter. But the language is not passed back in any way when I click on "Forgotten password". I can see in console that the "login_hint" is returned, but not "ui_locales". Is there any way that I can add this parameter in the error?

Comment: Sending error code is the legacy way to do password reset in Azure AD B2C. Recommend way is to do it embedded. It doesn't answer your question hence why not providing it as a solution. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset

Comment: @ChadHasbrook as I wrote in my question, this is a choice we've made this choice not to use the sub journeys to be able to make some validation steps on our side. This is by design and won't change.

Comment: sub journeys has nothing to do with using the legacy method or the recommended method. sub journeys is an implementation detail to organize steps.

Comment: @ChadHasbrook and how do you do the recommended way? By embedding sub journeys (just look at the sample you gave me). So there is no point on arguing on semantics here. The client need is : get back to its own environment if a user clicks on "Password reset" with the proper language that was set as ui_locales in the Azure AD B2C page.

Comment: Ideally it sends an error message back to the application. Not sure how to append a queryString parameter. If you end up not figuring it out, an alternative approach is to create your own hyperlink outside the api-div that points back to your application and parse the ui_locales parameter from the URL onto the hyperlink and add as a queryString Parameter. Then, your Controller can just parse that out and send it back explicitly in the new request for password reset.